# why is nexthop ip print reversed with the ping command?

Tags: ip, ping

This question hit me today while I'm quite used to see it reversed, but actually, why is the nexthop ip noted reversed in the ping command ?

```
PING 10.8.0.8 (10.8.0.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 8.0.8.10)
From 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 8.0.8.10)
From 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 8.0.8.10)
From 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=4 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 8.0.8.10)
```

(10.8.0.8 is usually accessed via 10.8.0.1, but is not powered on thus the ping fails... but the question is about the "8.0.8.10" reversed)

Comment: You'll have to ask whoever runs the server at 10.8.0.1.

Comment: I guess I'll have to ask myself then... can you detail ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in iputils with Ubuntu.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/iputils/+bug/1892108

Comment: Seems to be there in upstream as well, where it got fixed: https://github.com/iputils/iputils/commit/e2e9a2dd4639924614bdbee43907a49134e8da19